# Parsing idx and sub formats of video subtitle files?

Tags: c#, file-format

I wrote an application in c# that can read *srd* files well, but now I need to add support for *idx* and *sub* files too. How can I parse these formats?

I parse the *srt* files as this[Code Project: Subtitle Synchronization with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32834/Subtitle-Synchronization-with-C) article describes. I don't know regular expressions and now want to parse the *idx* and *sub* files.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. What have you tried?

Comment: ... and what are srd files and how do they relate to idx & sub files?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To improve your question and attract great answers, I'd recommend you to (1) add some description about the file formats (maybe a link?) and (2) explain what you have already tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Google for 'idx format specification'
2. Find http://www.filesuffix.com/extension/idx.html
3. Page links to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSFilter
4. Wiki article links to http://sourceforge.net/projects/guliverkli2/files/DirectShow%20Filters/DirectVobSub%202.39/ where you can download sourcecode. In the source code you'll most likely find information about reading the idx/sub files.